# OS X Mavericks - Google Chrome Helpers memory usage

Tags: google-chrome, memory, osx-mavericks

Is it ok that Google Chrome uses so much memory?

[image: screenshot]

Is there a way to reduce the memory that Chrome uses?

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce the memory usage by going to *Chrome home* -> *Preferences* -> *Settings* -> *Show advanced settings* -> *Content settings* (under the *Privacy* heading) and select *Click to play* for all plug-ins. This will reduce memory usage, but you will have to click whenever you run a plug-in (including Flash ads).